# ¿Por qué se ejecuta este "if"?

Tags: java

¿**Por qué se ejecuta**-> if (this.cochesDentro < 50 && this.numCochesQueHanEntrado < 250) { **dentro del método**  public void entraCoche(Coche c) {  **si no se cumple la condición?**
**Entran más de 250 coches al parking, superando la capacidad máxima, se pasa el "if" por el forro y además entran más de 50 a la vez, lo cual es otra condición del "if". *

```
 public void entraCoche(Coche c) {

        if (this.cochesDentro < 50 && this.numCochesQueHanEntrado < 250) {
            try {
                semaEntrada.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            Random r = new Random();
            int aleatorio = r.nextInt(50) + 1;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(aleatorio);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            System.out.println("El coche " + c.getNombre() + " ha entrado al parking.");
            numCochesQueHanEntrado++;
            cochesDentro++;
            semaSalida.release();
            semaEntrada.release();
            System.out.println("Coches dentro del parking: " + this.cochesDentro);
            System.out.println("Han entrado un total de " + this.numCochesQueHanEntrado);
        }
    }
```

```
public class Coche extends  Thread{
    private String nombre;

    private Parking par;
    public Coche( String nombre,Parking p) {

        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.par=p;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

            par.entraCoche(this);


        par.saleCoches(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: La concurrencia es lo que tiene. Falta parte de tu programa para entenderlo bien, pero quizás uno de los problemas está en que el método entraCoche no está sincronizado. Imagina que lanzas 1000 hebras de coches y por casualidad todas ejecutan ese if cuando el parking está vacío y luego empiezan a bloquearse en el semaforo. La sincronización ha llegado tarde, ya están todos dentro del parking.